# Как протестировать сайт на мобильном (через WiFi) c browser-sync

Tags: gulp, браузер, testng

В проекте использую `browser-sync` с такими настройками:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
browserSync({
    server: {
        baseDir: 'app'
    },
    notify:false
  })
});
```

При запуске указываются пути:

```
Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://192.168.56.1:3000
-------------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:3001
UI External: http://192.168.56.1:3001
```

Вебверсия `http://localhost:3000` открывается без проблем.

Но почему-то не получается зайти с мобильного по пути `http://192.168.56.1:3000`

Как еще можно настроить доступ? (OS Windows 10)

**UPD**

Сделала разрешение "WIN10 by allowing Node.js:Server-side Javascript on "Private" network in "Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Firewall\Allowed applications" - но это не помогло(

**UPD**

помог переход на macos

Comment: Может поможет: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/390

Comment: на 90% уверен, что блочит брандмауэр или если у вас nod то у него свой фаервол, отключите временно и проверьте

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте в центре управления сетями и общим доступом перейти в адаптеры и отключить все кроме действующего адптера к роутеру. У меня так браузер синк пытался открыться сначала в хамачи, а потом в вайфае которого нет уже год.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вывод ipconfig в командной строке Windows.
У меня была такая проблема из-за того что 192.168.56.1 был зарезервирован для VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло переключение с общественной сети на домашнюю.

Comment: что такое "общественная" сеть? я работаю в основном в домашней сети.

Comment: Нужно зайти в "Центр управления сетями". И там это есть. Так у меня на Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Как написал

> user3769489.  проблема из-за того что 192.168.56.1 был зарезервирован для VirtualBox.

нужно узнать в ipconfig свой ip из Адаптер Ethernet Ethernet: IPv4-адрес.
в моём случае 192.168.1.65  и указать в brower-sync host: "192.168.1.65" <- свой ip